# VBA: DoCmd Transferspreadsheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Im trying to import an excel worksheet into Access table.
Here is my code:

```
Sub test2()

 Dim xlApp As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = False

Dim fd As Object
Set fd = xlApp.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

Dim selectedItem As Variant

If fd.Show = -1 Then
    For Each selectedItem In fd.SelectedItems
        Debug.Print selectedItem
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "POR", selectedItem, True, "POR Plan!A1:Z100"
    Next
End If

Set fd = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I get an error at the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "POR", selectedItem, True, "POR Plan!A1:Z100" line. When I dont specify the range and omit "POR Plan!A1:Z100", it takes the very first worksheet in my excel workbook and works fine. 
But I would like to get the POR Plan worksheet.

Comment: Add the dollar sign at the end of sheet/range e.g. `POR Plan!A1:Z100$`.

Comment: By the way you don't need `xlApp` to perform this task.

Comment: @KostasK. Added the dollar sign to it. but it returns with an error : microsoft access database engine could not find the object "Por Plan!A1:Z100$"

Comment: You can give a name to the range `A1:Z100` e.g. "ImportRange" and then use the name in TransferSpreadsheet.

Comment: I tried giving a name and setting the range but i get the Method of cells of object _global failed error. and i tried adding the dollar to the end of the worksheet as well

Comment: It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import from Excel into Access (this runs in Access).

```
Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
' has field names
blnHasFieldNames = False

' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
' contains the EXCEL files
strPath = "C:\Documents\"

' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
' the data are to be imported
strTable = "tablename"

strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
' EXCEL file after it's been imported
'       Kill strPathFile

      strFile = Dir()
Loop
```

Or, push data from Excel to Access (this runs in Excel).

```
Sub ADOFromExcelToAccess()
' exports data from the active worksheet to a table in an Access database
' this procedure must be edited before use
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long
    ' connect to the Access database
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
        "Data Source=C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb;"
    ' open a recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "TableName", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable  
    ' all records in a table
    r = 3 ' the start row in the worksheet
    Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0 
    ' repeat until first empty cell in column A
        With rs
            .AddNew ' create a new record
            ' add values to each field in the record
            .Fields("FieldName1") = Range("A" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldName2") = Range("B" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldNameN") = Range("C" & r).Value
            ' add more fields if necessary...
            .Update ' stores the new record
        End With
        r = r + 1 ' next row
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

There are several other variations of these two sample scripts.  Do some Googling and you will get all kinds of ideas for all kinds of things.